# osx Python 2.7 gives "E ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)"

Tags: python, macos, nupic

I installed nupic and when I run the test I get the error `E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)`. I am not sure what this error means.

```
$ ./scripts/run_nupic_tests.py -u
    ============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.10 -- pytest-2.5.1 -- /Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/bin/python
plugins: cov, xdist
collecting ... collected 7 items / 79 errors

tests/unit/nupic/data/utils_test.py:59: UtilsTest.testParseSdr PASSED
tests/unit/nupic/data/utils_test.py:65: UtilsTest.testParseStringList PASSED
tests/unit/nupic/data/utils_test.py:35: UtilsTest.testParseTimestamp PASSED
tests/unit/nupic/data/utils_test.py:62: UtilsTest.testSerializeSdr PASSED
tests/unit/nupic/data/utils_test.py:49: UtilsTest.testSerializeTimestamp PASSED
tests/unit/nupic/data/utils_test.py:54: UtilsTest.testSerializeTimestampNoMS PASSED
tests/unit/nupic/data/utils_test.py:71: UtilsTest.testStripList PASSED

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_______________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/utils_test.py ________________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/algorithms/anomaly_likelihood_jeff_test.py _
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
___ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/algorithms/anomaly_likelihood_test.py ____
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/algorithms/anomaly_test.py _________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/algorithms/cells4_test.py __________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
___ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/algorithms/cla_classifier_diff_test.py ___
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_____ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/algorithms/cla_classifier_test.py ______
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
___ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/algorithms/fast_cla_classifier_test.py ___
tests/unit/nupic/algorithms/fast_cla_classifier_test.py:35: in <module>
    import cla_classifier_test
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_____ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/algorithms/knn_classifier_test.py ______
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
______ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/algorithms/nab_detector_test.py _______
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_______ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/algorithms/sp_overlap_test.py ________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (digit out of range in long)
___________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/algorithms/svm_test.py ___________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/algorithms/tp10x2_test.py __________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
__________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/data/aggregator_test.py ___________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
___________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/data/dictutils_test.py ___________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
___________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/data/fieldmeta_test.py ___________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
______ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/data/file_record_stream_test.py _______
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
____________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/data/filters_test.py ____________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/data/functionsource_test.py _________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_______ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/data/inference_shifter_test.py _______
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/data/record_stream_test.py _________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_____ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/data/generators/anomalyzer_test.py _____
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
__ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/data/generators/pattern_machine_test.py ___
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
__ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/data/generators/sequence_machine_test.py __
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
______ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/encoders/adaptivescalar_test.py _______
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/encoders/category_test.py __________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/encoders/coordinate_test.py _________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
___________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/encoders/date_test.py ____________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
___________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/encoders/delta_test.py ___________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
___ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/encoders/geospatial_coordinate_test.py ___
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
__________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/encoders/logenc_test.py ___________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
___________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/encoders/multi_test.py ___________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
___ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/encoders/pass_through_encoder_test.py ____
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/encoders/random_distributed_scalar_test.py _
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
__________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/encoders/scalar_test.py ___________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/encoders/scalarspace_test.py ________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/encoders/sdrcategory_test.py ________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
 ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/encoders/sparse_pass_through_encoder_test.py 
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
___________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/engine/network_test.py ___________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_______ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/engine/syntactic_sugar_test.py _______
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
____ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/engine/unified_py_parameter_test.py _____
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
 ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/frameworks/opf/clamodel_classifier_helper_test.py 
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
______ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/frameworks/opf/clamodel_test.py _______
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_____ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/frameworks/opf/opf_metrics_test.py _____
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
 ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/frameworks/opf/common_models/cluster_params_test.py 
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_______ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/math/array_algorithms_test.py ________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
_________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/support/decorators_test.py _________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/support/object_json_test.py _________
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
 ERROR collecting tests/unit/nupic/support/consoleprinter_test/consoleprinter_test.py 
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:134: in find_module
    co = _read_pyc(fn_pypath, pyc)
/Users/magaga/.virtualenvs/nupic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:311: in _read_pyc
    co = marshal.load(fp)
E   ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
===================== 7 passed, 79 error in 68.37 seconds ======================
```

I tried to reinstall python and everything but could not solve the issue.

Comment: How did you install nupic? From binary using `pip install` or local compilation? Also, what version of OS X?

Answer (score 0):

It means the tests are trying to use data that couldn't be deserialized. My guess is they stored some test data using the Python `marshall` library, which according to the docs generally shouldn't be used:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html

```
If you’re serializing and de-serializing Python objects, use the pickle module instead – the performance is comparable, version independence is guaranteed, and pickle supports a substantially wider range of objects than marshal.
```

Chances are the test data was generated on a different platform or using a different Python version than you're using.

I would file a bug report on their project page.